# Eclipselink parameter binding is wrong when using IN clause for Multitenant

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, bind, multi-tenant

Here is the JPQL:
SELECT e FROM TestEntity e WHERE e.owner IN :owners
Here is its SQL and parameter binding:

```
SELECT TENANT_ID, ID, OWNER_ID FROM TEST.TESTENTITY WHERE (((TEST.TESTENTITY.OWNER_ID, TEST.TESTENTITY.TENANT_ID) IN ((?,?))) AND (TENANT_ID = ?))
    bind => [1, 236, 1]
```

TENANT_ID = 1 
OWNER_ID = 236

The expected SQL should be:

```
SELECT TESTENTITY.TENANT_ID, TESTENTITY.ID, TESTENTITY.OWNER_ID FROM TEST.TESTENTITY JOIN TEST.USER ON TEST.USER.ID=TEST.TESTENTITY.OWNER_ID AND TEST.USER.TENANT_ID=TEST.TESTENTITY.TENANT_ID WHERE (((TEST.USER.OWNER_ID, TEST.USER.TENANT_ID) IN ((?,?))) AND (TESTENTITY.TENANT_ID = ?)) bind => [236, 1, 1]
```

There are two mistakes in its generated sql:

1. No join. It's fine if this is a optimization. But I think if it needs to be optimized, it could be:

   SELECT TENANT_ID, ID, OWNER_ID FROM TEST.TESTENTITY WHERE ((TEST.TESTENTITY.OWNER_ID IN (?)) AND (TENANT_ID = ?))
       bind => [236, 1]

Because TENANT_ID is appended at the end already.

2. Parameter binding order. TENANT_ID is bound to owner.id while OWNER_ID is bound to owner.tenantId. This may be a bug.

Do I misunderstand? Any sugguestion is welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Your analysis seems right - file a bug with EclipseLink at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink  My guess is that the multitenant feature just wasn't incorporated well with the optimization

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your reply. Looking forward to the fix though we have work arround for this case.